# AWS machine as additional 107 GB Disk attached

Tags: amazon-web-services

I haven't attached any disk, why my `fdisk` output is showing below output?

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

output:

```
Disk /dev/mapper/docker-202:1-268523-pool: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 65536 bytes
```

Comment: do : `df -h` and `lsblk`

Comment: loop0                        7:0    0  100G  0 loop 
└─docker-202:1-268523-pool 253:0    0  100G  0 dm   
loop1                        7:1    0    2G  0 loop 
└─docker-202:1-268523-pool 253:0    0  100G  0 dm